# How can I read http response body using selenium java?

Tags: java, selenium

I need to read API response JSON file using selenium and java. I have got the code till getting response of http requests. But not sure about how to dive further down and get message body.

Comment: can you add your response above

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question clearly then you are asking for reading and validating the response that you got.

The best practice is to create the pojo class for your response. For example if your response is in below format

```
{
"response":{
    "userId": 1,
    "firstName": "Suhail",
    "lastName": "Ahmed",
}
"data": {},
"timestamp": "2022-07-27T11:21:55.347Z"
}
```

You need to creare a pojo class for the same.

GetUserDeatilsResponse.java

```
public class GetUserDeatilsResponse {
private UserDeatilsResponseAttr response;
private String data;
private String timestamp;


public UserDeatilsResponseAttr getUserDeatilsResponseAttr() {
    return response;
}

public void setUserDeatilsResponseAttr(UserDeatilsResponseAttr response) {
    this.response = response;
}

public String getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(String data) {
    this.data = data;
}


public String getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}
}
```

UserDeatilsResponseAttr.java

```
public class UserDeatilsResponseAttr{
private int userId;
private String firstName;   
private String lastName;

public int getFirstName() {
    return userId;
}

public void setFirstName(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
}
```

And to validate lastName field, in your test class call the response like below

Test.class

```
public class Test{

@Test
public void test1(){
    // get your response here
    GetUserDeatilsResponse userDetailsResponse = response.as(GetUserDeatilsResponse.class);
    
    System.out.println(userDetailsResponse.getUserDeatilsResponseAttr.getLastName())
}

}
```